# Problem with ajax tabcontainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i use from  ajax tabcontainer .and i want to when value of hiddenfield is not 1(value of hiddenfield change when i click in gridview,i don`t have problem with set value for hiddenfield) and user click in email tab it alerts and stays in first tab.but in my code it alert and changes tab.i want to stay in cuurent tab.
i write this code but it dosen`t work.
please  help me.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" %>


     <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>                
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org   


<script type="text/javascript">
   function SetActiveTab() {
   var hfd = $get('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>');
   if (hfd.value != "1") {
       alert("hitttttttt");
       var ctrl = $find('TabContainer1');
       ctrl.set_activeTab(ctrl.get_tabs()[0]);


   }

}
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Ajax Control - Tabs </title>
 </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
         <b>Tabs Demonstration</b> <br />
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
         <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:TabContainer runat="server" ID="TabContainer1" Height="138px"  ActiveTabIndex="0"
        Width="402px">
        <asp:TabPanel runat="server" ID="Panel1" HeaderText="Address" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>Address:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" /></td></tr>
                        </table>
                   </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>

        <asp:TabPanel runat="server" ID="Panel3" HeaderText="Email" OnClientClick="SetActiveTab" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                Email: <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" />

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>

        <asp:TabPanel runat="server" ID="Panel2"  HeaderText="Login Details" >
            <ContentTemplate>
             <table>
           <tr> <td>User Name:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server" /></td></tr>
           <tr> <td>Password:</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" runat="server" /></td></tr>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>

    </asp:TabContainer>


</form>
```

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but could revise your question? I tried to revise, to help you, but I think I did not quite got the whole meaning...

Comment: And keep in mind that if you want to check the value of a hiddenfield in the page_load, one should change it before such event, otherwise it will always be the default value during that check.

Answer (score 0):

The one solution I found is to remove OnClientClick handler and use the javascript below:

```
 function pageLoad() {
    var tabContainer = $find('<%= TabContainer1.ClientID %>');
    var hfd = $get('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>');

    var oldSetActiveTab = Function.createDelegate(tabContainer, tabContainer.set_activeTab);

    tabContainer.set_activeTab = function (value) {
        if (value.get_id() == '<%= Panel3.ClientID %>' && hfd.value != "-1") {
            alert("oops");
        }
        else {
            oldSetActiveTab(value);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @@dear OneHalfTrackMindMan thanks.but i don`t know how can i use from it?should i call page load function call in page load?please help me.

Comment: @@dear OneHalfTrackMindMan thanks.but i don`t know how can i use from it?should i call page load function call in page load?please help me

Comment: You don't need to call the pageLoad. More about it you can read here: http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/